# Method on page load giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi friends i have bindgrid function on page load which is giving following error..

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          bindGrid();
        }
```

Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> **Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace**:

> [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e) +130
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() +105
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3572

What it means...Thanks in Advance

Comment: what does `bindGrid` method do? Can you share that code too?

Comment: it bind the data to grid

Comment: @Dalorzo if(!Page.IsPostback) this too not working what this error means specially

Comment: Put this function `bindGrid()` in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
bindGrid();
}
```

As I don't have the `BindGrid()` function so there must be some conflicting of events happening. And my code prevents that conflicting because it is only binding the grid only when the post back is not happened. If it still doesn't work than this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/Vipin/archive/2012/03/05/throwifmaxhttpcollectionkeysexceeded-error-message-when-doing-postback.aspx) will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

From my end it sounds like your method bindGrid is conflicting with other PostBack events. Try this instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
         if(!IsPostBack) bindGrid();
}
```